# Gunicorn Flask распараллеливание

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Если я запускаю своё Flask приложение через Gunicorn и задаю несколько рабочих потоков - то на каждый из потоков запускается по одному инстансу Flask приложения?

Я написал телеграмм бота и у него имеется примитивный кэш в виде словаря. Бот через вебхук интегрируется во Flask приложение. Мой главный вопрос в следующем - на каждый поток, созданный Gunicorn, будет создаваться новый инстанс бота со своим кэшем?

Подскажите правильно ли я думаю и подкиньте статей по теме если есть.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gunicorn использует распаралеливание, но в одном потоке (корутины и все такое).
http://words.volant.is/articles/understanding-gunicorns-async-worker-concurrency-model/ Статья по теме.

Таким образом можно использовать обычный словарь для кэша, если вы запускаете приложение под Gunicorn.

Comment: gunicorn может использовать как несколько потоков так и несколько процессов. Green threads не единственный способ одновременно несколько запросов обрабатывать в gunicorn и более того это не способ, использующийся по умолчанию.

Comment: @jfs напишите свой ответ - подискутируем.